# Zauner's conjecture

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, conjectures

The conjecture is as follow: In $\mathbb{C}^{n}$, there exists $\{v_1,\cdots,v_{n^2}\}$ such that the following holds: 
$$ \left| \left \langle v_i, v_j \right \rangle \right|  = \begin{cases} 1  & i = j\\ \frac{1}{n+1} & i \ne j\end{cases}$$
I have a prove for when $n = 2$, basically what I did is just assuming without loss of generality that one of the vectors is $\begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$, and brute force the rest of the vectors. I'm curious where this construction fails when $n \ge 3$, or has the conjecture already been proven? I can't seem to find literature that it has been proven on the Internet though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is a recent update, with a proof that [Zauner's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIC-POVM) (the existence the existence of $n^2$ equiangular lines in $n$ complex dimensions) holds for $n\leq 67$: [SIC-POVMs: A new computer study](http://arxiv.org/abs/0910.5784) (2010).

It remains an open question whether the conjecture is true in all dimensions. Some insight into the difficulty of the conjecture is given in [The Lie Algebraic Significance of Symmetric Informationally Complete Measurements](http://arxiv.org/abs/1001.0004) (2011). See also this [MO post](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/2897/) and http://physicsoverflow.org/382

This [blog](https://dustingmixon.wordpress.com/2015/03/10/zauners-conjecture-is-true-in-dimension-17/) from 2015 gives more background.